# Is there a way to turn off the grey "potential fixes" indication in the vertical scroll bar in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, .net, workflow, visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio for .Net/C# there's a grey rectangle indicator that tells me my code has "Potential Fixes" suggestion. I find this distracting. Any way to turn this particular indicator off?

Two examples given below with the different bar types.

[image]

[image]

Comment: There is a feature request for the option to disable scrollbar markers for suggestions: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/show-error-markers-in-scroll-bars-but-not-suggesti/1295415

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio, go to Tools > Options > Text Editor > All Languages > Scroll Bars >
Uncheck 'Show annotations over vertical scroll bar' and you are done.

There are multiple types of annotations, like changes, errors etc. You can uncheck a particular type or all of them.

Comment: Thanks. While unticking the 'Errors' option here _does_ remove the grey annotations, it also removes the red code error annotation, which I would like to keep.

Answer (score 0):

Go to <kbd>Debug</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>Text Editor</kbd> > <kbd>All Language</kbd> > <kbd>Scroll Bars</kbd>

Then check and uncheck *Show horizontal scroll bar* and *Show vertical scroll bar*.

[image]

Comment: This removes the bar in entirety. I wish to only remove the particular annotation above, but keep all other information.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to remove them by doing the following:

> click the down arrow by the light bulb that pops up in the code where the suggestion is;
> click "suppress or configure severity";
> then set configure severity for the desired type of suggestion to "none";

This made disappear from the vertical scroll bar all the suggestions of that type.